# Hive External table on AVRO file producing only NULL data for all columns

Tags: hadoop, hive, avro, spark-avro, hive-table

I am trying to create an `Hive external table` on top of some `avro` files which are generated using `spark-scala`. I am using `CDH 5.16` which has `hive 1.1`, `spark 1.6`.

I created `hive external table`, which ran successfully. But when i query the data i am getting `NULL` for all the columns. 
[My problem is similar to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33310149/sqoop-import-as-avro-data-file-gives-all-values-as-null-when-creating-external-a)

Upon some research, i found out it might be the problem with schema. But i couldn't find the schema file for these avro files in the location.

I am pretty new to `avro` file type. Can some one please help me out here.

Below is my `spark` code snippet where i have saved the file as `avro`:

```
df.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).format("com.databricks.spark.avro").save("hdfs:path/user/hive/warehouse/transform.db/prod_order_avro")
```

Below is my hive external table create statement:

```
create external table prod_order_avro
(ProductID string,
ProductName string,
categoryname string,
OrderDate string,
Freight string,
OrderID string,
ShipperID string,
Quantity string,
Sales string,
Discount string,
COS string,
GP string,
CategoryID string,
oh_Updated_time string,
od_Updated_time string
)
STORED AS AVRO
LOCATION '/user/hive/warehouse/transform.db/prod_order_avro';
```

Below is the result i am getting when i query the data:
`select * from prod_order_avro`

[image: Result]

At the same time, when i am reading these `avro` files using `spark-scala` as `dataframe` and printing them, i am getting proper result.
Below is the `spark` code i used to read these data:

```
val df=hiveContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").option("header","true").load("hdfs:path/user/hive/warehouse/transform.db/prod_order_avro")
```

[image: avro files data when read through spark-scala]

My question is,

- While creating these `avro` files, do i need to change my `spark`
  code to create schema files separately or will it be embedded with
  the files. If needs to be separate, then how to achieve it?
- If not how to create `hive` table so that schema is retrieved from the
  file automatically. I read that in latest version hive takes care of
  this issue by itself if schema is present in the files.

Kindly help me out here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved this..it was a schema issue. The schema was not embedded with the `avro` files.So i had to extract schema using `avro-tools` and  passed it while creating table. Its working now.

I followed the below steps:

1. Extracted few data from `avro` files stored in `hdfs` into a file in
   local system. Below is the command used for the same:

   `sudo hdfs dfs -cat /path/file.avro  | head --bytes 10K > /path/temp.txt`
2. Used `avro-tools getschema` command to extract schema from this data:

   `avro-tools getschema /path/temp.txt`
3. Copy the resulting schema(it will be in the form of `json` data) into a new 
   file with `.avsc` extension and upload the same into `HDFS`
4. While creating the `Hive External table` add the below property to it:

   `TBLPROPERTIES('avro.schema.url'='hdfs://path/schema.avsc')`

Comment: @Vaishak- Could you please update your answer with some more details. can be useful for a new person.

Comment: @vikrantrana i have edited my answer with more details